# Lower prediction accuracy when using preProcess within train()

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Am new to R and machine learning, so please excuse the basic question...

Am experimenting with the "spam" dataset in kernlab library. And using functions from caret library.

Objective:

Predict "type" over 58 remaining variables in "spam"

I tried two different ways of pre-processing:

PRE-PROCESSING DATASETS BEFORE `train()`

```
# preprocess all 57 predictors, leave out response variable #58
preproc = preProcess(trainset[-58], method = "BoxCox")

preprocTrain = predict(preproc, trainset[,-58])
preprocTrain$type = trainset$type

preprocTest = predict(preproc, testset[,-58])
preprocTest$type = testset$type

set.seed(123)
fit2 = train(type~., data=preprocTrain, method = "glm")
predict2 = predict(fit2, newdata = preprocTest)
confmat2 = confusionMatrix(predict2, preprocTest$type)

fit2$results
confmat2$overall
```

NOTE:

```
fit2 Accuracy = 0.93 and confmat2 Accuracy = 0.92
```

And then, 
 USING `preProcess` WITHIN `train()`

```
set.seed(123)
fit3 = train(type~., data=trainset, method="glm", preProcess = "BoxCox")

Predict using pre-processed test set from before

predict3 = predict(fit3, newdata = preprocTest)
confmat3 = confusionMatrix(predict3, preprocTest$type)

fit3$results
confmat3$overall
```

Now, 
`fit3 Accuracy = 0.93` BUT `confmat3 Accuracy = 0.75`

Please help me understand why this sharp drop? Shouldn't confmat3 accuracy be same as confmat2 accuracy? Where is the difference? Also, in the second prediction, I get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In predict.BoxCoxTrans(object$bc[[i]], newdata[, i]) :
  newdata should have values 0
2: In predict.BoxCoxTrans(object$bc[[i]], newdata[, i]) :
  newdata should have values 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: in your predict3 you should not use preprocTest but just testset. fit3 contains the instructions to run the preprocess on the newdata. Now it will run the preprocess on an already preprocessed dataset. That will impact your result.

Comment: Thank you, @phiver! Just checked that and it works!